# Spring Roo JSF: reCaptcha is not showing in a dialog

Tags: jsf, primefaces, spring-roo, recaptcha

I try to add recaptcha in the Roo-generated xhtml:

```
<p:dialog id="createDialog" header="#{messages.label_create} Person" modal="true" widgetVar="createDialogWidget" dynamic="true" visible="#{personBean.createDialogVisible}" resizable="true" maximizable="true" showEffect="fade" hideEffect="explode">
  <p:ajax event="close" update=":dataForm:data" listener="#{personBean.handleDialogClose}" />
  <p:outputPanel id="createPanel">
    <h:form id="createForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <h:panelGrid id="createPanelGrid" columns="3" binding="#{personBean.createPanelGrid}" styleClass="dialog" columnClasses="col1,col2,col3" />

      <p:captcha id="createReCaptcha" theme="white"/>

      <p:commandButton id="createSaveButton" value="#{messages.label_save}" action="#{personBean.persist}" update="createPanelGrid :growlForm:growl" />
      <p:commandButton id="createCloseButton" value="#{messages.label_close}" onclick="createDialogWidget.hide()" type="button" />
    </h:form>
  </p:outputPanel>
</p:dialog>
```

And no recaptha is shown.... Where I am wrong?

Comment: do have any errors? Have you defined PUBLIC_CAPTCHA_KEY

Comment: no errors, but when I press "save" there is an error, smth like "error jdt_26: ...", which I think about the captcha is invalid. and, yes, my public and private keys for localhost are defined in web.xml.

but I have not yet defined any captcha processing in the server-side pojo, maybe here the problem?

Comment: Does it work when you place your captcha code outside the p:dialog? p:dialog tend to be a pain in the *ss.

Comment: you are right, outside the p:dialog it works perfectly... do you know the receipt to fix the pain?)

Answer (score 1):

Remove the dynamic="true" from your p:dialog

Comment: It works, thanks a lot! Unfortunately, unable to "Vote Up" due my very low reputation...